# Using puppeteer to take a screenshot of an element lager than the viewport result in blank space

Tags: javascript, user-interface, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm trying to take a screenshot of an element whose larger than the viewport.
The screenshot return the viewport content and then blank content.

```js
it("Test", async () => {
    let [ell, height, width] = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return [
        document.getElementsByClassName("app")[0],
        document.getElementsByClassName("app")[0].scrollHeight,
        document.getElementsByClassName("app")[0].scrollWidth,
      ];
    });

    // console.log(ell);
    console.log(height);
    console.log(width);

    const el = await page.$(".app");
    // console.log(el);
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 600));
    // const image = await el.screenshot();
    const image = await el.screenshot({
      clip: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width,
        height,
      },
    });

    // const image = await page.screenshot({
    //   clip: {
    //     x: 0,
    //     y: 0,
    //     width,
    //     height,
    //   },
    // });

    expect(image).toMatchImageSnapshot({
      failureThreshold: "0.10",
      failureThresholdType: "percent",
    });
  })
```

I have tried taking pictures of the `page` and of the element, but in all cases I receive a large image which only the upper part (the viewport) filled with content.

Same as described here:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1779

How can I fix this? How can I take a screenshot of an element larger than the viewport (and overflow the `body`)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set option captureBeyondViewport?

Smth like:

```js
const element = await page.waitForSelector(".app");
const elementBounding = await element.boundingBox();
if(!elementBounding) {
  throw new Error('Failed to get element bounding');
}
const image = await page.screenshot({
      clip: elementBounding,
      captureBeyondViewport: true,
      });
```

Comment: Didn't work. I should note that the `body` is smaller than the ".app" `div` element, which overflows.

Comment: @itaied does property `fullPage: true` also not work for you?

Comment: correct. Doesn't work either